# Null Pointer exception passed by test method

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, android-testing

> Method that needs to be tested - located in AnalyticsServiceImpl.java class
>
> ```
> public void trackSplashState(MeasurementViewEnum measurementViewEnum) {
>     HashMap<String, Object> data = createCommonData(measurementViewEnum);
>     MeasureServiceImpl.StartStatus status = mMeasureService.getLaunchStatus();
>     switch (status) {
>         case INSTALL:
>             data.put(APP_EVENT_INSTALL, INSTALL);
>             break;
>         case LAUNCH:
>             data.put(APP_EVENT_LAUNCH, LAUNCH);
>             break;
>         case UPDATE:
>             data.put(APP_EVENT_UPDATE, UPDATE);
>             break;
>     }
>     trackState(measurementViewEnum, data);
> }
> ```
>
> Test class

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = TestConfig.SDK)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class AnalyticsServiceImplTest {

    @Module(includes = TestAppModule.class, injects = AnalyticsServiceImplTest.class, overrides = true)
    static class TestModule {
    }

    @Inject
    AnalyticsServiceImpl analyticsServiceImpl;
    @Inject
    MeasureServiceImpl measureService;
    @Inject
    Context mContext;
    @Inject
    LoginService mLoginService;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<HashMap<String, Object>> data;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<String[]> varargs;

    private ArgumentCaptor<MeasurementViewEnum> enumArgumentCaptor;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Services.initialize(new AnalyticsServiceImplTest.TestModule()).inject(this);
        enumArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MeasurementViewEnum.class);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void trackSplashState_shouldReturnInstall_whenLaunchStatusEqualsINSTALL() throws Exception {
        analyticsServiceImpl = mock(AnalyticsServiceImpl.class);
        MeasureServiceMock measureServiceMock = new MeasureServiceMock();
        measureServiceMock.setStatus(MeasureServiceImpl.StartStatus.INSTALL);
        analyticsServiceImpl.mMeasureService = measureServiceMock;
        analyticsServiceImpl.trackSplashState(MeasurementViewEnum.SPLASH);
        verify(analyticsServiceImpl, times(1)).trackState(enumArgumentCaptor.capture(), data.capture());
    }
}
```

when I run this test case I got null pointer exception at the last line. I'm a bit new to unit testing. Can you please explain what is the mistake that I have done in this code?

Comment: Try to show the entire Test class with @ArgumentCaptor definition etc.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski- I have added the full code of my test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You are mocking the SUT which simply wont work:

```
analyticsServiceImpl = mock(AnalyticsServiceImpl.class);
```

You will be verifying its `trackState` method so you need to Spy on it:

```
analyticsServiceImpl = spy(new AnalyticsServiceImpl());
```

**2)** You are capturing the inputs but you are not asserting them in any way. I guess you missed that:

```
verify(analyticsServiceImpl, times(1)).trackState(enumArgumentCaptor.capture(), data.capture());
Map<String, Object> dataCaptured = data.getValue();
MeasurementViewEnum enumCapture = enumArgumentCaptor.getValue();

// assert these values
```

**UPDATE:**

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
   MockitoAnnotation.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry @Maciej. I thought I really fixed but still, I'm getting it :( I can share my files if you can send your email.

Comment: Hi Maciej Thank you . Actually, I found the issue. I had to do some modifications in MeasureServiceMock class. Then it worked correctly. Thank you for your support.